# What does this command do? "openssl genrsa -aes256 -out example.key 2048"

Tags: openssl, aes, rsa

I'm confused about what this statement is doing. "openssl genrsa -aes256 -out example.key 2048"? I believe that it's creating an rsa private key, however I don't know what the rest of it is doing. Thanks for any help guys.

Comment: What specifically do you find confusing? 
 Here is the documentation that will probably help: 
 https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man1/genrsa.html

Comment: I guess I'm trying to fully comprehend what's going on in this statement. is this generating an RSA private key, encrypting the private key with AES256 bit encryption before outputting it to the file example.key 2048?

Comment: Does the 2048 on the end mean anything?

Answer (score 9):

As the comment says, you need to break it down by looking at the [documentation](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man1/genrsa.html).

So lets breakdown the command line:

> The genrsa command generates an RSA private key.

So using genrsa you are creating a RSA private key.

> -aes256

Means:

> -aes128, -aes192, -aes256, -aria128, -aria192, -aria256, -camellia128, -camellia192, -camellia256, -des, -des3, -idea
>
> ```
> These options encrypt the private key with specified cipher 
> before outputting it. If none of these options is specified no 
> encryption is used. If encryption is used a pass phrase is 
> prompted for if it is not supplied via the -passout argument.
> ```

So you are asking the new private key to be output encrypted with aes256.   So openssl will prompt you for the password to used in the AES256 encryption of the private key.

> -out example.key

Means:

> -out filename
>
> ```
> Output the key to the specified file. If this argument is 
> not specified then standard output is used.
> ```

So you are asking for the new private key to be output to the file example.key.

> 2048

Means:

> numbits
>
> ```
> The size of the private key to generate in bits. This must be 
> the last option specified. The default is 2048 and values less
> than 512 are not allowed.
> ```

So you are asking for the private key size to be 2048 bits in length.  Since this is the default you could just drop it from the command line and you will still get a 2048 bit length private key.

If you want to know more about key size, check out the [wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_size) on the subject.